# How do I add fit and position dynamically-generated QGroupBox on a screen?

Tags: python, pyside, qgroupbox

I need to construct a screen dynamically based on the contents of a dynamically generated JSON file that contains a variable number of widgets, along with variable sizes, positions, colors, etc. I would like for the contents to fill the entire screen.

The problem is, after getting the Scene and View to fit nicely, with a nice little border around the edge, adding a GroupBox -- well, setting the title anyway, makes the Scene? View? larger that the screen.

The following very stripped-down example has the right appearance until I uncomment the `self.box.setTitle("Speaker 1")`. The original code has several GroupBoxes with CSS styling, and they look right. However, the Scene / View border at the bottom of the screen disappears, no matter what height I give to the GroupBoxes.

(I tried writing this initially without using View / Scene but couldn't position / size QGroupBoxes the way I wanted them.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui  import *


class Viewport(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Viewport, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.setFixedSize(self.parent.width  - 21,
                          self.parent.height - 21)
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(0, 0,
                                    self.parent.width  - 42,
                                    self.parent.height - 42,
                                    self)
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.box = QGroupBox(self)
#       self.box.setTitle("Speaker 1")       # THIS BREAKS IT
        self.box.setObjectName("speaker1")
        self.box.setGeometry(12, 12, 200, 200)


class UI(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, width, height, parent=None):
        super(UI, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent  = parent
        self.width   = width
        self.height  = height
        self.view = Viewport(self)
        gridLayout = QGridLayout()
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.view, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.setLayout(gridLayout)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.showFullScreen()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
screen_resolution = app.desktop().screenGeometry()
width, height = screen_resolution.width(), screen_resolution.height()
ui = UI(width, height)
ui.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

From the more complicated thing I'm trying to do:

[image: Without QGroupBoxes, bottom border appears]
Without QGroupBoxes, bottom border of screen appears.

[image: With QGroupBoxes, bottom border of screen disappears]
With QGroupBoxes, bottom border of screen disappears

(The included code above should give the same effect except that it has only one QGroupBox, and I haven't styled it to show the borders, nor made it as tall as the ones in my second screenshot.)

Adding the title also causes the QDialog that contains everything to NOT use the whole screen any longer. Note the appearance of the system bar at the top of the second image.

Comment: I do not understand you, explain better please, it would be great if you put images of what you get and what you want to obtain.

Comment: @eyllanesc The quickest way to see the problem is to run the code, but I'll add some images.

Comment: I have executed your code and I do not understand your problem. ;P

Comment: @eyllanesc I've added images and more explanation.

Comment: The code that you sample does not reproduce what you show, when I execute your code I get the following: https://imgur.com/a/cP7o7

Comment: @eyllanesc Interesting. Yours apparently does the correct thing. I copied and pasted from my post, to be certain that I hadn't somehow corrected the problem.  However, on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) I'm still getting the bad results. My first image looks like your first. My second looks like yours with the bottom cut off and no longer occupying the full screen.

Comment: I'm using the Debian packages python-pyside-* which are all PySide 1.2.2, and Python 3.5, in case that's the difference. (PySide 1.2.4 only supports up to Python 3.4.)

Comment: I'm running it in arch linux with pyside 1.2.4, I think you need to add the code of the green edges since that is not by default in Qt.

Comment: Why do you use QGraphicsView?

Comment: @eyllanesc I get the error even without the green edge (using the code I posted). And I'm using QGraphicsView because I couldn't get it to work without it. My attempts to generate QGroupBoxes and lay them out without knowing their sizes or positions or order of appearance in the JSON files failed when I tried to do it any other way. (That's because I'm not very good with PySide, apparently.) I couldn't generate the grid layout without knowing how tall / wide every widget is in relation to every other widget that might appear... I'm  open to alternative ideas. ;-)

Comment: Is that you comment that you have a file that tells you the sizes and so far you do not show it. Also if the sizes and positions are fixed you just have to use setGeometry(QRect(posx, posy, width, height)) for each item, obviously you must pass as a parent to the window. QGraphicsView has another utility, that's why it adjusts automatically. So far I do not understand what you want to do.

Comment: I do not understand the background of the problem, I understand the error you have at this moment, and one of the causes is that you are unnecessarily using QGraphicsView. You could explain your background idea in more detail.

Comment: Try with this code: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/23a92afa071b9366deb0821ea1e674fa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161947/discussion-between-ubuntourist-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: Check the following code: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/01ef7eb60efc2554bb7bf69ef271b25c